# How to check if one string contains the letter s followed by two unknown letters and ended with 1

Tags: php, regex, string

How can I check this in php?

```
$var1 = "pluto_saa1";
$var2 = "pluto_sab1";
$var3 = "pluto_sac1";
$var4 = "pluto_sad1";

$var5 = "pluto_test";
```

For example, **var1, var2, ... var5** contains the `s` followed by two unknown letters and ending with `1` but **var5** contain something undesired.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should do it:

`/s[a-zA-Z]{2}1/`

2 upper or lower case letters followed by an 1.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex

```
/s[a-zA-Z]{2}1/
```

`[a-zA-Z]` would match a single uppercase or lowercase letter

`{n}` is a quantifier which matches preceding pattern n times

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$patterns = '/pluto_s(.*?)1/is';
$var1 = "pluto_saa1";
$var2 = "pluto_sab1";
$var3 = "pluto_sac1";
$var4 = "pluto_sad1";

$var5 = "pluto_test";
$array = array($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5);

foreach($array as $data)
{
    if( preg_match($patterns, $data, $matches))
    {
        var_dump($matches);
    }
}
```

This will output

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'pluto_saa1' (length=10)
  1 => string 'aa' (length=2)

array (size=2)
  0 => string 'pluto_sab1' (length=10)
  1 => string 'ab' (length=2)

array (size=2)
  0 => string 'pluto_sac1' (length=10)
  1 => string 'ac' (length=2)

array (size=2)
  0 => string 'pluto_sad1' (length=10)
  1 => string 'ad' (length=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function check_str($str) {

    $pattern="%_s+[a-z]{2}1$%";


if(preg_match($pattern,$str)) {

    echo 'ok';



}

}
check_str($var1);
```